# Apache port opened not get via url

Tags: php, python, linux, apache, ubuntu

I have an apache server. I want to run PHP and Python on same server. PHP run on port 80. It works properly. Python is running on port 5000. I have check **netstat -tulpn** in my server, It seems port 5000 opened.

[Open Port List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9xS9.png)

But I cannot open this port via browser like http://40.114.53.94:5000/

Any one can help ?

Comment: Did you change the SElinux fcontext for the port 5000 like this? semanage port -a -t httpd_t -p tcp 5000
And please share the screenshot or error message you get when trying to open the URL.

Comment: semanage port -l | grep http_port_t   I have check with code. It looks the port is opened

Comment: maybe some router blocks this port - and only admin/provider can change it.

Comment: is python using address `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 allow any IP Address . right ?
In My python code I have used port 5000

Comment: `0.0.0.0` or empty string means that program will uses all NIC (network cards in computers) to receive requests - if you use `127.0.0.1` then it will not receive external requests.

Comment: Yes. In this scenario, this can be access from any computer right ?

Comment: if you use `0.0.0.0` then it can be access from other computers - if you have open port 5000 and there is no router which blocks port 5000 :)

Comment: to eliminate possible network issues, get on the server and telnet localhost 5000 and see if you get a connection .

Comment: I have try telnet 40.114.53.94 5000. It shows connected